# Create list of imports service provider on unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Angular, and I have a new team that told me to implement unit testing on an old project with Angular 8. So after investigating that, I decided to use Karma + Jasmine, and I created `.spect.ts` document like this:

```js
describe("CashFlowSalariesComponent", () => {
      let fixture: ComponentFixture < CashFlowSalariesComponent > ;
      let instance;
      let profile: ProfileModel;

      beforeEach(async() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            ToastrModule.forRoot({
              positionClass: "toast-bottom-right",
            }),
          ],
          declarations: [CashFlowSalariesComponent],
          providers: [
             ApiService,
    UserService,
    ProfileService,
    VettingStatusService,
    SkillService,
    ApplicationRoleService,
    SeniorityLevelService,
    PlacementStatusService,
    EducationLevelService,
    UtilsService,
    ShirtSizeService,
    GenderService,
    TimeZoneService,
    CountryService,
    CityService,
    PostalCodeService,
    StateService,
    ClientSectorService,
    JobService,
    ClientService,
    PulsecheckQuestionService,
    PulsecheckMasterService,
    ExchangeRateService,
    DepartmentService,
    ExpenseService,
    ProfileRoleService,
    SkillCategoriesService,
    ProfileActivityService,
    ProfileSalaryActivityService,
    TimeSheetService,
    HolidayService,
    RequestTimeOffService,
    TimeOffTypeService,
    InvoiceService,
    PulsecheckDetailService,
          ],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CashFlowSalariesComponent);
        instance = fixture.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();

        profile = new ProfileModel();
        (instance as any).exchangeRate = 18.92;
      });

      afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
      });

      it("To test instance creation of component", () => {
        expect(instance).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

As you can see, I had to import many services from providers because my ApiService had injected them, so if I no add them, it returned an error like this:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for {serviceName}!

So each time I call the ApiService on each component, developers should copy and paste from this component all the services. So my question is: is this a way to create a class or something to import all providers in once without copying and pasting code each time? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that could help you with your issue:

- You can define your services as `providedIn: 'root'` in this case you don't need to provide them in any module or test. Angular would resolve them automatically.

example:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {}
```

- You could also define global providers in your `test.ts` file.

example:

```
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule], 
    providers: [...],
})
class GlobalTestingSetupModule {}


TestBed.initTestEnvironment([BrowserDynamicTestingModule, GlobalTestingSetupModule], platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Also, instead of `HttpClientModule` it is preferable to use `HttpClientTestingModule` in unit tests.

Comment: Shouldn't we actually `export` those common modules in GlobalTestingSetupModule, instead of importing? It seems to fail if we just import: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-testing-examples-x8j6ce?file=src%2Ftest.ts

Comment: You should export them. The reason why it's needed here is that ngModel is a directive and to share directives from other modules you need either to import FormsModule directly or export FormsModule in another module, like GlobalTestingSetupModule in our case. 
Note, that to "share" providers you would only need to import the module, no export is required.